# MoviePy cannot display non-English text properly

Tags: python, imagemagick, moviepy

I have used MoviePy to create a video from an image and add some annotation to the bottom of an image. The problem is that the text that I want to add is Vietnamese (not English) so MoviePy cannot display it properly.

Specifically, below is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from moviepy.editor import *

# create clip from image
clip = ImageClip('img/1.jpg').on_color((1920, 1080))
clip = clip.set_duration(2)

# add annotation to clip
txtclip = TextClip('Truyện Kiều Nguyễn Du', fontsize=50, color='red')
cvc = CompositeVideoClip([ clip, txtclip.set_pos(('center', 'bottom'))])
cvc = cvc.set_duration(2)

# write video to file
cvc.write_videofile("text.mp4", fps=24)
```

Instead of displaying `Truyện Kiều Nguyễn Du`, it displays `Truy?n Ki?u Nguy?n Du`.

I think the main problem is from `ImageMagick` because when I use command

`convert -size 400x200 xc:khaki -gravity Center -pointsize 30 -annotate 0 "Truyện Kiều Nguyễn Du" u8_an.png`

ImageMagick also creates an image with the same problem. Please let me know if you can help me fix it.

UPDATE: I also try to convert the string to utf-8 but it does not work

`t = u'Truyện Kiều Nguyễn Du'.encode('utf-8')
txtclip = TextClip(t, fontsize=50, color='red')`

Comment: It could be a problem with the default font. Specify one that you know contains Vietnamese chars. You may also need to explicitly encode the text to UTF-8.

Comment: BTW, with Unicode questions it's always a good idea to mention the Python version and the OS.

Comment: Hi, the version of Python that I used is 2.7.12. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit. I also explicitly encode the text to UTF8 but it does not work

``
t = u'Truyện Kiều Nguyễn Du'.encode('utf-8')
txtclip = TextClip(t, fontsize=50, color='red')
``
would you give me more suggestion of the font?

Comment: You should add that info into the question itself. I suggest trying the font that your text editor or console use, since it looks like they handle Vietnamese.

Comment: Also, because you're using Python 2 you should mark all Unicode string literals in your code with `u`, like you did in the code in the comment.

Comment: The problem has been fixed. I use font FreeMono in TextClip and done. Thanks for your support

Comment: I really recommend switching to Python 3, as it has superior Unicode support.

Comment: @tndoan Post it as an answer! Then accept yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the suggestion of @Gloin, I post my solution as the answer.

It is fixed by using different font for `TextClip`. Specifically, this is the solution

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from moviepy.editor import *

# create clip from image
clip = ImageClip('img/1.jpg').on_color((1920, 1080))
clip = clip.set_duration(2)

# add annotation to clip
t = u'Truyện Kiều Nguyễn Du'.encode('utf-8')
txtclip = TextClip(t, fontsize=50, color='red', font='FreeMono')
cvc = CompositeVideoClip([ clip, txtclip.set_pos(('center', 'bottom'))])
cvc = cvc.set_duration(2)

# write video to file
cvc.write_videofile("text.mp4", fps=24)
```

I think the problem is that we need to consider (1) use utf-8 to encode the string (2) use the suitable font to push to ImageMagick (in my case `FreeMono` is the suitable one)